# Odoo Server Error when trying to install Expense Tracker

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I am running Odoo 10 on a vmware machine on my esxi 6. And it happened the same when I try to install other apps.

I am new to this and do not know how to debug.

```
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 866, in call_button
action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 854, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/api.py", line 681, in call_kw
return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/api.py", line 672, in call_kw_multi
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/addons/base/module/module.py", line 410, in button_immediate_install
return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/addons/base/module/module.py", line 484, in _button_immediate_function
modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 78, in new
odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 337, in load_modules
loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 235, in load_marked_modules
loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 159, in load_module_graph
_load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='demo')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 95, in _load_data
tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 848, in convert_file
convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 918, in convert_xml_import
obj.parse(doc.getroot(), mode=mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 802, in parse
self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 698, in _tag_record
f_val = self.id_get(f_ref)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 785, in id_get
res = self.model_id_get(id_str, raise_if_not_found)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 791, in model_id_get
return self.env['ir.model.data'].xmlid_to_res_model_res_id(id_str, raise_if_not_found=raise_if_not_found)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1027, in xmlid_to_res_model_res_id
return self.xmlid_lookup(xmlid)[1:3]
  File "<string>", line 2, in xmlid_lookup
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 87, in lookup
value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1016, in xmlid_lookup
raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid)
ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: base.user_demo" while parsing /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/addons/resource/data/resource_demo.xml:90, near
<record id="resource_designer" model="resource.resource">
        <field eval="100" name="time_efficiency"/>
        <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_demo"/>
        <field name="name">Designer</field>
        <field eval="1" name="active"/>
        <field name="calendar_id" ref="timesheet_group1"/>
        <field name="resource_type">user</field>
    </record>
```

Comment: Not really, I have to reinstall it...

Answer (score 1):

In Odoo 10, Use *base.public_user* instead of *base.user_demo* id reference.

Try with following code:

```
<record id="resource_designer" model="resource.resource">
    <field eval="100" name="time_efficiency"/>
    <field name="user_id" ref="base.public_user"/>
    <field name="name">Designer</field>
    <field eval="1" name="active"/>
    <field name="calendar_id" ref="timesheet_group1"/>
    <field name="resource_type">user</field>
</record>
```

Comment: I modified the file but encounter 500 error. And also I checked the file and discovered that it may be caused by the demo data. Thus I planned to create another vm and install odoo with empty database.

Comment: Make sure you have created database with demo data. Otherwise it will not work. And also don't forget to add dependency *base* module in your custom module.